# Different behaviors for different size in C++ (Firebreath source code)

Tags: c++, templates, firebreath

I encounter a confused question when I go through the source code of firebreath ([src/ScriptingCore/Variant.h](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ScriptingCore/variant.h))

```
    // function pointer table
    struct fxn_ptr_table {
        const std::type_info& (*get_type)();
        void (*static_delete)(void**);
        void (*clone)(void* const*, void**);
        void (*move)(void* const*,void**);
        bool (*less)(void* const*, void* const*);
    };

    // static functions for small value-types 
    template<bool is_small>
    struct fxns
    {
        template<typename T>
        struct type {
            static const std::type_info& get_type() { 
                return typeid(T); 
            }
            static void static_delete(void** x) { 
                reinterpret_cast<T*>(x)->~T(); 
            }
            static void clone(void* const* src, void** dest) { 
                new(dest) T(*reinterpret_cast<T const*>(src)); 
            }
            static void move(void* const* src, void** dest) { 
                reinterpret_cast<T*>(dest)->~T(); 
                *reinterpret_cast<T*>(dest) = *reinterpret_cast<T const*>(src); 
            }
            static bool lessthan(void* const* left, void* const* right) {
                T l(*reinterpret_cast<T const*>(left));
                T r(*reinterpret_cast<T const*>(right));

                return l < r;
            }
        };
    };

    // static functions for big value-types (bigger than a void*)
    template<>
    struct fxns<false>
    {
        template<typename T>
        struct type {
            static const std::type_info& get_type() { 
                return typeid(T); 
            }
            static void static_delete(void** x) { 
                delete(*reinterpret_cast<T**>(x)); 
            }
            static void clone(void* const* src, void** dest) { 
                *dest = new T(**reinterpret_cast<T* const*>(src)); 
            }
            static void move(void* const* src, void** dest) { 
                (*reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest))->~T(); 
                **reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest) = **reinterpret_cast<T* const*>(src); 
            }
            static bool lessthan(void* const* left, void* const* right) {
                return **reinterpret_cast<T* const*>(left) < **reinterpret_cast<T* const*>(right);
            }
        };
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct get_table 
    {
        static const bool is_small = sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*);

        static fxn_ptr_table* get()
        {
            static fxn_ptr_table static_table = {
                fxns<is_small>::template type<T>::get_type
                , fxns<is_small>::template type<T>::static_delete
                , fxns<is_small>::template type<T>::clone
                , fxns<is_small>::template type<T>::move
                , fxns<is_small>::template type<T>::lessthan
            };
            return &static_table;
        }
    };
```

The question is why the implementation of static functions for the big value-types (bigger than void*) is different from the small ones.

For example, static_delete for small value-type is just to invoke destructor on T instance, while that for big value-type is to use 'delete'.

Is there some trick? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(*reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest))->~T();` `**reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest) = **reinterpret_cast<T* const*>(src);` That made me gasp. The assignment operator is supposed to be called on a live object, not one that was previously destructed.

Comment: It isn't calling that on a previously destructed object, it's calling the destructor and then assigning the new data into it; basically it's just reusing the memory. The object gets destructed, but the memory was never freed. This is only used (as an optimization) when the new type is exactly the same as the old type.

Comment: I have added a link to the original file so that people can actually see everything that is going on; this is only a small piece and is missing the most important part -- how it is used.

Comment: @Taxilian - if you want to assign a new value, there is no need to destroy the old value first. And if you do, you will have to use placement new to recreate an object.

Comment: @Taxilian: I think MatthieuM is right, it's calling the assignment operator on a destructed object which isn't allowed.  You are right that the memory is reusable, first it has to be reconstructed.   Should be `new (**reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest)) T (**reinterpret_cast<T* const*>(src));`  (placement new)

Comment: It's using a copy constructor; this is not a commonly done thing, but it is not undefined behavior. This works. I promise it does. Feel free to try to prove me wrong; I'd love to see you break this code.

Comment: @Taxilian `class Test { char isCtored; public: Test() : isCTored(true) {}; ~Test() { isCtored = false; } Test& operator=(Test const& other) { assert(isCTored); return *this; } };`

Comment: I can't produce the error you describe using the code you suggest; let's continue this on the other thread (moved to chat) if you're interested. For any reading along know that the cases listed here have unit tests around them in FireBreath; on the off chance that the "undefined behavior" may change in a dangerous way with your computer, the unit test will let you know.

Comment: @Taxilian: I certainly did not want to suggest that it would not "work". Undefined behavior simply means that it may not be portable, but many people implicitly rely on other assumptions that make the code non-portable. Glad to know there are unit-tests to ensure it works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Firebreath uses a dedicated memory pool for its small objects, while large objects are allocated normally in the heap. Hence the different behaviour. Notice the placement `new` in `clone()` for small objects, for instance: this creates the new object in a specified memory location without allocating it. When you create an object using placement `new`, you must explicitly call the destructor on it before deallocating memory, and this is what `static_delete()` does.

Memory is not actually deallocated because, as I say, it looks like a dedicated memory pool is in use. Memory management must be performed somewhere else. This kind of memory pool is a common optimisation for small objects.

Comment: Actually, it seems that they are storing the small objects in place directly instead of incurring the cost of a redirection. I find the practice frankly dubious, as evidenced by the number of `reinterpret_cast` going on.

Comment: @MatthieuM. They're certainly depending on copy semantics for small objects (but not for large) in `lessthan` (which should be interesting if you have a small object which isn't copyable).  The code is so error filled as to be unusable.

Comment: @JamesKanze: As I commented on your answer, I guess these are internal functions. Notice that OP explains that he was examining the source code, not reading interface documents. This kind of optimisations may be valid if you know the objects you will actually use with the functions.

Comment: Heh. that's an interesting observation by both of you since this code has been used in FireBreath for 2 years and by large companies without every experiencing any such errors.  Extensive tests have also been done with valgrind and also with tools on windows (LeadDetector and Rational Purify, possibly others) and no leaks have been detected in this code. There is no dedicated memory pool in use, but the original poster did not include the full file so you are missing some important bits.

Comment: @Taxilian: It may work now, but it's using undefined behavior.  It's definitely not safe, and not guaranteed to work.

Comment: editing this comment because it was unnecessarily rude. This is not undefined behavior; it's just not something that is commonly done. This is using the same type of assignment that occurs when you use a line like "MyObject a = b"; it uses the copy constructor to assign a constructed object to that memory. It is not undefined. Please feel free to try to prove me wrong on that if you want to, but this will always work.

Comment: So I've looked a bit more into this; it is conceivable that you could create a class that would have problems if the behavior of the assignment operator and the copy constructor differed strongly; however, the behavior is still going to be predictable depending on what object type you use. The memory is not deallocated; the destructor is just called. As long as the class is designed properly and is initializing variables, it should be fine. You could certainly make a poorly built class that would break this.

Comment: The point, though, is that FireBreath only allows certain types, which have all been tested. Therefore the behavior could be dangerous in certain cases, but it is not undefined.

Comment: @Taxilian The code will fail for a lot of classes, including just about any class in the standard library.  Assignment requires a fully defined object; if the class allocates dynamic memory, it must free it in the destructor or an assignment (before reallocating), and cannot free it in a copy constructor.  This is fundamental C++, see Scott Meyers _Effective C++_, for example.

Comment: Interesting, because I use STL classes in it all the time and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Taxilian Seeming to work is one possible undefined behavior.  The code clearly contains undefined behavior.

Comment: @Taxilian I've looked at the code.  The copy constructor of `variant` will also lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

What does the internal documentation say?  If the author hasn't
documented it, he probably doesn't know himself.

Judging from the code, the interface to small objects is different than
that to large objects; the pointer you pass for a small object is a
pointer to the object itself, where as the one you pass for a large
object is a pointer to a pointer to the object.

The author, however, doesn't seem to know C++ very well (and I would
avoid using any code like this).  For example, in `move`, he explicitly
destructs the object, then assigns to it: this is guaranteed undefined
behavior, and probably won't work reliably for anything but the simplest
built-in types.  Also the distinction small vs. large objects is largely
irrelevant; some “small” objects can be quite expensive to
copy.  And of course, given that everything here is a template anyway,
there's absolutely no reason to use `void*` for anything.

Comment: I guess these functions are only used internally and small objects are actually built-ins. As for the `void*`, I can only guess that they are trying to mimic the interface of functions like `operator new` and `operator delete` for reasons unknown; we might need to see more library code for that. But, again, this are just guesses.

Comment: James: don't assume the author doesn't know C++ just because you don't understand how the code works; this code has been really heavily tested (by me and others) and works exactly as it should in all cases we have tried; it is simply reusing the memory. It isn't directly using the assignment operator, it's actually using the copy constructor; so in other words, it calls the destructor for the old object, then the constructor for the new (with the copy constructor) on the same memory; it's just reusing memory. A little unusual, but this is highly optimized code.

Comment: @Taxilian That's not the code that is posted above.  The code posted above does an explicit delete, then an assignment.  Although it will work for simple cases, this is undefined behavior.  Given that the author doesn't seem to understand the difference between assignment and initialization, and makes extensive use of `void*` in contexts where he actually knows the type, one can only conclude that he doesn't know C++, and is thinking in terms of C++.

Comment: Err... no, no it doesn't.  The only explicit delete is in the "static_delete" function for the "large" version, and it doesn't do any assignment afterwords.  Also, he *doesn't* know the type, because the void* comes from *outside* of the template specialized code.

Comment: I highly recommend you look at the full source for the file; you're missing a lot of details with the snippet posted here.

Comment: @Taxilian In the version posted, there is an explicit delete, followed by an assignment, in both the small and large versions of `move`.  Calling `move` on any type which has a non-trivial destructor will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @Taxilian a typo on my part.  Assigning to a destructed object is undefined behavior.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4620/discussion-between-taxilian-and-james-kanze)

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your question to include a link to the original source file, since obviously most of those answering here have not read it to see what is actually going on.  I admit that this is probably one of the most confusing pieces of code in FireBreath; at the time, I was trying to avoid using boost and this has worked really well.

Since then I've considered switching to boost::any (for those itching to suggest it, no, boost::variant wouldn't work and I'm not going to explain why here; ask another question if you really care) but we have customized this class a fair amount to make it exactly what we need and boost::any would be difficult to customize in a similar manner. More than anything, we've been following the old axim: if it ain't broke, don't fix it!

First of all, you should know that several C++ experts have gone over this code; yes, it uses some practices that many consider dubious, but they are very carefully considered and they are consistent and reliable on the compilers supported by FireBreath. We have done extensive testing with valgrind, visual leak detector, LeakFinder, and Rational Purify and have never found any leaks in this code. It is more than a bit confusing; it's amazing to me that people who don't understand code assume the author doesn't know C++. In this case, Christopher Diggins (who wrote the code you quoted and the original cdiggins::any class that this is taken from) seems to know C++ extremely well as evidenced by the fact that he was able to write this code. The code is used internally and is highly optimized -- perhaps more than FireBreath needs, in fact. However, it has served us well.

I will try to explain the answer to your question as best I remember; keep in mind that I don't have a lot of time and it's been awhile since I really dug in deep with this.  The main reason for "small" types using a different static class is that "small" types are pretty much built-in types; an int, a char, a long, etc. Anything bigger than void* is assumed to be an object of some sort. This is an optimization to allow it to reuse memory whenever possible rather than deleting and reallocating it.

If you look at the code side-by-side it's a lot clearer. If you look at delete and clone you'll see that on "large" objects it's dynamically allocating the memory; it calls "delete" in delete and in clone it uses a regular "new". In the "small" version it just stores the memory internally and reuses it; it never "delete"s the memory, it just calls the destructor or the constructor of the correct type on the memory that it has internally. Again, this is just done for the sake of efficiency. In move on both types it calls the destructor of the old object and then assigns the new object data.

The object itself is stored as a void* because we don't actually know what type the object will be; to get the object back out you have to specify the type, in fact. This is part of what allows the container to hold absolutely any type of data. That is the reason there are so many reinterpret_cast calls there -- many people see that and say "oh, no! The author must be clueless!" However, when you have a void* that you need to dereference, that's exactly the operator that you would use.

Anyway, all of that said, cdiggins has actually put out a new version of his any class this year; I'll need to take a look at it and probably will try to pull it in to replace the current one. The trick is that I have customized the current one (primarily to add a comparison operator so it can be put in a STL container and to add convert_cast) so I need to make sure I understand the new version well enough to do that safely.

Hope that helps; the article I got it from is here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dynamic_typing.aspx

Note that the article has been updated and it doesn't seem to be possible to get to the old one with the original anymore.

**EDIT**

Since I wrote this we have confirmed some issues with the old variant class and it has been updated and replaced with one that utilizes boost::any.  Thanks to dougma for most of the work on this.  FireBreath 1.7 (current master branch as of the time of this writing) contains that fix.